# How to launch the Settings from my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, setting

In one of my apps I need to launch the settings app to change the keyboard language. Please some one help me regarding this problem with some sample code or idea.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, and should not, do this. [Localize](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) your application as normal and, if the user has selected an alternate language for the phone, it will be used from within your application. Your application should not be changing system wide settings.

Comment: I think the question is about changing the keyboard format & launching the Settings app from within the app for the user's convenience. The user will then manually select the keyboard options (this will not be done by the app programmatically).

Comment: hay! I'm not changing setting from my apps directly i need to go setting of iphone from my apps on button click. can it be possible or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to launch the Settings app from your app.

Comment: hay! I'm not changing setting from my apps directly i need to go setting of iphone from my apps on button click. can it be possible or not?

Comment: I think this is exactly what I said. You cannot click a button & launch the settings app. The user has to do it manually.